# coding UTF8 python

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, utf-8

I have created Django project on my laptop and successfully run this on Heroku.
I cloned the github repository of that project on another laptop (the same Ubuntu version as on the first), and I get an error message now.

I should specify:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

on other laptop and write `var` as

```
text = u"какой-то текст"
```

But I needn't do this on the first laptop.
What is different?
The same Ubuntu 14.04 on both.

Comment: You don't need to write `u"str"` in python 3. Maybe you have different python versions on your laptops?

Comment: Check python version ? python2 vs python3 by default maybe ?

Comment: I need 'python3 manage.py runserver' localy yes?)

Comment: You first need to make sure you're using the same python version on both laptops... Using a (properly setup) virtualenv is a good way to avoid this kind of problems.